# JSF and AJAX: hiding part of site until first ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm trying to create a page where some content will be displayed after ajax request. Here is part of my code:

```
<h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            Retrive object by id: <h:inputText id="myInput" value="#{myManager.id}"/> 
            <h:commandButton value="ok" action="#{myManager.getById}" >
                <f:ajax execute="myInput" render="resultRow" />
            </h:commandButton>
        <h:panelGroup id="resultRow" >
            <br />
            You retrived object which id is:
            <h:outputText value="#{retrivedObject.id}" />
            and its name is:
            <h:outputText value="#{retrivedObject.name}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My problem is taht the *"You retrived object which id is: "* is rendered even before I retrive any object. I want it to be hidden until I click my command button. Is it possible to do only with jsf + html (this have to be done with ajax)? I could use some javascript if I will have to, but I prefer not.

I tried to solve this by `rendered="#{!retrivedObject.id==0}"` (my object can't have id 0), but this doesn't work - panel group isn't rendered at all and when I call ajax reqest it is unable to find "resultRow" id.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Does `if (!retrievedObject.getId() == 0) {}` really work in normal Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for but you can always wrap the panelGroup in a div and set the div visibility to hidden, then use javascript to change the visibility when you click the command button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rendered` attribute like this :

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:form>
        Retrive object by id: <h:inputText id="myInput" value="#{myManager.id}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="ok" action="#{myManager.getById}" >
            <f:ajax execute="myInput" render="resultRow" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:panelGroup id="resultRow">
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{retrivedObject ne null}">
                <br />
                You retrived object which id is:
                <h:outputText value="#{retrivedObject.id}" />
                and its name is:
                <h:outputText value="#{retrivedObject.name}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I've never seen `not` used as a binary operator, do you mean `not empty retrivedObject`?